# GNOME-Terminal - Copy file and place in separate directory

Tags: gnome-terminal, paste

I was wondering how I could copy a file and paste it in a separate directory (like a different folder besides the current one) in the GNOME-Terminal. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal ?

```
cp file $HOME/new_location
```

change "file" and "$HOME/new_location" to your needs, example

```
cp music.mp3 ~/Music
```

~ is short hand for $HOME or /home/your_user